# How do I connect odoo and postgres with docker compose?

Tags: postgresql, docker, odoo, docker-compose

I have been trying for a while and I can't get this working. I want to connect odoo (openERP) with postgres through docker-compose.

Here is my yml:

```
# Odoo server
app:
    build: ./containers/odoo
    ports:
      - "8000:8069"
    links:
      - db
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: myuser
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword

# PostgreSQL server
db:
    build: ./containers/postgres
    environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: myuser
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
```

Dockerfiles are just like this:

```
FROM library/odoo

# For customizing purposes
```

I run it and the db name and password seleccion page apears and works ok. After init process, main page shows up almost in [blank](http://snag.gy/ZpNtw.jpg).

How do I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your odoo dockerfile based on the official dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/

Comment: I used "FROM library/odoo", so I think yes.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check there is no 404 error during page loading (using Developper pane in Chrome F12/Network) ?

Most of the time blank page in Odoo is caused by js/css loading failure. If so, you need to checl NodeJS et less install within your docker image.

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose file,

```
 version: '2'
 services:
  database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    container_name: database
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo
    volumes:
      - /data-disk/postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
  odoo:
    image: odoo8
    container_name: odoov8
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    links:
      - database
    depends_on:
      - database
    environment:
      - PGHOST=database
      - PGUSER=odoo
      - PGPASSWORD=odoo
    volumes:
     - /home/username/company-files/debian:/etc/odoo
```